# Vuejs: data disappears on page refresh. Data persistance issue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, state, pinia

I want to watch for `selectedRecipe` changes. Right now if I click on recipe#1, then go back using the browser's 'back button' and click on recipe#2 I can see the correct recipe, but if I press the back button again and try to reach recipe#1 it will always show me the last one I clicked, which is recipe#2, even though the query param always matches the recipe I clicked on. Also, refreshing the page makes the data disappear.

Here are the state properties:

```js
export const state = () => {
    return {
        popularRecipes: [],
        recipeByKeyword: [],
        paginatedRecipes: [],
        selectedRecipe: null,
        recipesCount: 0,
        pending: false,
    };
};
```

and the watcher in main.js:

```js
watch(
    () => pinia.state.selectedRecipe,
    selectedRecipe => {
        if (selectedRecipe) {
            localStorage.setItem(
                'selectedRecipe',
                JSON.stringify(selectedRecipe)
            );
        }
    },
    { deep: true }
);
```

To be able to see the particular recipe details, I have a click event, and if I click on a recipe, I save its data in the `selectedRecipe` state property using this function:

```
// ItemCard.vue
const handleClick = () => {
    storeRecipe.selectRecipe(props.recipe);
};
```

I use this event on router-link in different components, like here in `ItemCard`:

```
// ItemCard.vue
<router-link
    class="card__link"
    :to="{
    name: 'recipeDetail',
    params: { recipe: recipe.slug },
    }"
    @click="handleClick"
    >View more</router-link
>
```

The prop `recipe` is the property that I pass from a parent component `ItemSwiper` to the child `ItemCard`:

```
// ItemSwiper.vue
<Slide
    v-for="recipe in storeRecipe.popularRecipes"
    :key="recipe.recipe_id">
    <ItemCard :recipe="recipe" :pending="storeRecipe.pending" />
</Slide>
```

Pinia store action:

```
selectRecipe(recipe) {
    this.selectedRecipe = recipe;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Looking for a solution.

UPDATE:
The issue with data disappearing on page reload is fixed with the use of this plugin:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/pinia-plugin-persistedstate

The rest remains unresolved.

Comment: It's unknown what happens when you "click" and "go back" in your app, the question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . If you don't implement persistence, there will be no persistence. Pinia has persistence plugins to avoid implementing it

Comment: @EstusFlask I used this plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pinia-plugin-persistedstate and the issue with the data disappearing on page reload is gone now. But the issue with back button remains. Meaning that if I click on multiple recipes and go back, I'll always see the details of the last one I clicked, even though the query param always matches the recipe I clicked on. I updated the question with more details. Please look.

Comment: It's unclear how data is handled and why this could happen, please, provide a way to reproduce.

Comment: @EstusFlask sorry, it's to difficult to reproduce this huge project. I'll wait for others to reply. I think I provided enough information, but if you need more details please let me know.

Comment: @EstusFlask do you need to know how my pinia actions look like or how I receive data on the server?

Comment: It's unclear how pinia data is related with routes, that's where the problem supposedly occurs, and code in the question doesn't show the big picture. Could be a problem with the way you handle route params. Pinia code can possibly help but it's hard to say. This may be clear to you but not to somebody who didn't see your project. MCVE I linked above is for such cases, it's the requirement for SO questions to keep them as precise as necessary. "I'll always see the details of the last one I clicked" - see where?

Comment: @EstusFlask "I'll always see the details of the last one I clicked" means when I click on recipe#1 and then go back, click on recipe#2, and then go back again to see recipe#1 once more, I can see the slug param for the recipe#1 in url, but instead of the data for recipe#1 I can see the data for recipe#2, because it was the last recipe I visited. And it seems like it saves the last data in selectedRecipe.

Comment: @EstusFlask I just add params: `{ recipe: recipe.slug }` to the router-link. And here's the action `selectRecipe` (I updated the question, please look).

Comment: I'm not sure how it's supposed to work, it's not shown how params.recipe is used. You need it to be taken into account somehow, probably syncing store recipes to currentRoute.params.recipe when it's changed